# LaTeX table doesn't fit in linewidth after XSL Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, latex, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to convert a table from XHTML to LaTeX using XSLT (version 1.0), but the table doesn't fit in the document useful area (width - 16cm).

Tables without colspan fit exactly in the document useful area, but tables with colspan exceed this area.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Example

XHMTL table

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"> <strong>LOREM</strong></td> 
        <td colspan="10"><strong>IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET</strong></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td><strong>consectetuer</strong></td> 
        <td><strong>adipiscing</strong></td> 
        <td><strong>elit</strong></td> 
        <td><strong>Aenean</strong></td> 
        <td><strong>commodo</strong></td> 
        <td><strong>ligula</strong></td> 
        <td><strong>eget</strong></td> 
        <td><strong>dolor</strong></td> 
        <td><strong>Aenean</strong></td> 
        <td><strong>massa</strong></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Cum</strong></td> 
        <td>sociis</td> 
        <td>natoque</td> 
        <td>penatibus</td> 
        <td>magnis</td> 
        <td>parturient</td> 
        <td>montes</td> 
        <td>nascetur</td> 
        <td>ridiculus</td> 
        <td>Donec</td> 
        <td>felis</td> 
        <td><strong>ultricies</strong></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

xsl code

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:table">
    <xsl:text>\begin{center}&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{</xsl:text>

    <xsl:variable name="total_columns">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(xhtml:tr[1]/*/@colspan) + count(xhtml:tr[1]/*[not(@colspan)])"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:text>*{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$total_columns"/>
    <xsl:text>}{C}}&#10;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:text>\toprule&#10;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:for-each select="xhtml:tr">
        <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
            <xsl:text>\midrule&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="position() = 2">
            <xsl:text>\midrule&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:for-each select="xhtml:td|xhtml:th">
            <xsl:if test="self::xhtml:th">\bfseries</xsl:if>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@colspan">
                    <xsl:if test="current()/@colspan&gt;=0">
                        \multicolumn{<xsl:value-of select="current()/@colspan"/>}{
                        >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{
                        <xsl:value-of select="((16 div $total_columns) * current()/@colspan)"/>cm}}{
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:apply-templates/>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@colspan">
                    <xsl:if test="current()/@colspan&gt;=0">}</xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>&amp;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">\\&#10;</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:text>\\&#10;\bottomrule</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;\end{tabulary}&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>\end{center}</xsl:text>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Good question. As I am not particularly familiar with LaTeX: What exactly is wrong with your LaTeX output? Perhaps you could show a snippet of the output you expect?

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with the LaTeX, the table is generated, but even with the width limited to 16cm, the table exceed the area. I want a table with maximum width 16cm.

Comment: Then, this is not necessarily an XSLT problem. You'll need to find the LaTeX code that works for you _first_ - in order to change your XSLT stylesheet accordingly. In other words: what LaTeX code generates the table you want?

Comment: Not exactly on topic, but you might want to use TeXML (http://getfo.org/texml/) for tranforming XHTML>LaTeX with XSLT (where TeXML is intermediate step).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure what is wrong with the LaTeX, the table is generated, but even with the width limited to 16cm, the table exceed the area. Then, this is not necessarily an XSLT problem. Not exactly on topic, but you might want to use TeXML (getfo.org/texml) for tranforming XHTML>LaTeX with XSLT (where TeXML is intermediate step).